# Why doesnt decremented pointers return the right value?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, decrement

I am trying to decrement a pointer while setting values to what the pointer is poiting to.
When setting the values they show that they have been properly set, but when trying to retrieve them again it doesnt return the right values. Why is this, and how can I get it to work?

This is the code I tried:

```
int a = 0;
int* sp = &a;
int* start_sp = &a;

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    *sp = i;
    printf("%d, %d\n", *sp, sp);
    sp--;
}

sp = start_sp;
printf("\n");
    
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", *sp, sp);
    sp--;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
0, 6291028
1, 6291024
2, 6291020
3, 6291016
4, 6291012

0, 6291028
1, 6291024
0, 6291020
6283584, 6291016
0, 6291012
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* when your pointer is going out of bounds of the variable `a`.

Comment: You're modifying memory you never allocated. `how can I get it to work?` By actually using memory you _own_.

Comment: You’re both _trying_ to smash your stack _and_ printing pointers with the wrong format specifier?

Comment: Also note that the correct format to print a `void *` pointer is `%p`, and a cast is needed. Mismatching format specifier and argument type *also* leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: I have been tasked with using a local array declaration that saves all data on the stack of unknown size. As far as I have understood (this very well might be wrong) using `malloc` the data will be stored on the heap, and the same with a normal array declaration, but that wouldn't really work since the array is of an unknown size. How would I do this then? @tkausl

Comment: *"I have been tasked with using a local array declaration"* So where's the array?

Comment: I was thinking of using an "array" with a stack pointer like you would do in assembly since I couldn't think of another way to get an array that saves its data on the stack @dbush

Comment: @DaBoat What's wrong with `int a[100]` for example?

Comment: Wouldn't the data be stored in the heap and not the stack with `int a[100]`? I might be completely wrong about this... @dbush

Comment: @DaBoat No, only `malloc` and family allocate on the heap.  Arrays declared inside of a function reside on the stack.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up the misunderstanding @dbush

Comment: If the size of the array is `n`, you should use `< n` in the `for` loop, not `<= n`.

Comment: Yes, this was just for testing @barmar

Comment: @dbush Realised `int a[100]` wouldn't work since it is of size n

Comment: @DaBoat Then make it `int a[n]`

Comment: That is not allowed in c I think. I get an error message if I try this @dbush

Comment: @DaBoat It is.  If you get an error, you either declared the array at file scope instead of inside a function, or you're using MSVC which isn't fully compliant.

Comment: I tried `void foo(int n) {int a[n];}` Which didn't work for me @dbush

Comment: What compiler are you using that rejected that? VLA has been an optional feature since C99, and most compilers implement it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this, and how can I get it to work?

As you access the memory which does not belong to any object, you invoke an undefined behavior.

To work you need to assign the pointer with the reference of the object (in this case an element of array) and you need to be sure that `sp - n` references the same array;

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 6;
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n);
    int* sp = a + n - 1;
    int* start_sp = sp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        *sp = i;
        printf("%d, %p\n", *sp, (void *)sp);
        sp--;
    }

    sp = start_sp;
    printf("\n");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d, %p\n", *sp, (void *)sp);
        sp--;
    }
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: That needs to be `int* sp = a + n;` if the sp is going to be decremented through the loops.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't this be stored on the heap? I should have added this in the discription but I am trying to have it saved on the stack @ikegami